# Finding an integer vector perpendicular to a rational vector/solving a Diophantine equation with constraints.

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, diophantine-equations, diophantine-approximation

Essentially, I want to solve the following problem:

> Given a vector of rational numbers, $\vec{X}\in \mathbb{Q}^d$, find the smallest integer vector perpendicular to it.  That is, find $\vec{n}\in \mathbb{Z^d}$ such that $\vec{n}\cdot\vec{X} = 0$ and $|\vec{n}|$ is minimized.

In other words, find the integer solution to the equation $n_1 X_1 + n_2 X_2 + \cdots + n_dX_d = 0 $ with the added condition of minimizing $n_1^2 +n_2^2 + \cdots + n_d^2.$

My partial attempt at a solution: we can construct a basis of integer vectors that spans the $d-1$ dimensional space of vectors perpendicular to $\vec{X}$.  The desired $\vec{n}$ is some linear combination of these basis vectors.  So it is reduced to the following problem:

> Given a set of integer vectors $\vec{V_1}, \vec{V_2}, \vec{V_3}, \dots \in \mathbb{Z^d}$, find the set of coefficients $a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots$ such that the magnitude of $a_1\vec{V_1} + a_2\vec{V_2} + \dots \in \mathbb{Z}^d$ is minimized.

The recast version of the problem seems perhaps a bit clearer, but I am still not sure how (if possible) to turn it in to some analytic or even numerical algorithm, beyond trial and error.

Edit: previously, I incorrectly assumed that the coefficients $a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots$ would have to be integers.

Also, if there is no unique solution $\vec{n}$, any one such vector is desired.

Comment: I'm guessing you want to exclude the trivial solution $\vec{n}=0$? Then for $u=(X_1,\ldots,X_{d-1})$ and $A:=uu^{\top}+X_d^2I_{d-1}$ the problem boils down to finding $v\in\Bbb{Z}^{d-1}$ such that $k:=v^{\top}Av$ is minimal and divisible by $X_d$, assuming (wlog) that $X_d\neq0$.

Comment: Anyway in general there need not be a *unique* $v\in\Bbb{Z}^{d-1}$ minimizing the $2$-norm, not even up to sign. Perhaps it is better to ask for either *an* $\vec{n}\in\Bbb{Z}^d$ perpendicular to $\vec{X}$ with minimal $2$-norm, or *all* such vectors.

Comment: @Servaes yes, you are right, and I only need one such n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in\Bbb{Q}^d$ be given. If $x_i=0$ for some $i$ then the $i$-th basis vector $e_i$ is perpendicular to $x$, and its magnitude is minimal. So suppose that $x_i\neq0$ for all $i$. Scaling up, without loss of generality $x\in\Bbb{Z}^d$. Then the vector
$$y:=(x_2,-x_1,0,0,0,\ldots,0),$$
is perpendicular to $x$, and $||y||^2=x_1^2+x_2^2$. It follows that for a vector $z\in\Bbb{Z}^d$ perpendicular to $x$ of *minimal* magnitude we must have $z_k<\sqrt{x_i^2+x_j^2}$ for any pair of indices $1\leq i<j\leq d$, for every index $1\leq k\leq d$. This shows that any such minimal vector is contained in the box $[-(m-1),(m-1)]^d\subset\Bbb{Z}^d$, where
$$m:=\min_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\sqrt{x_i^2+x_j^2}.$$
Of course once you find a vector of smaller magnitude inside this box, you can restrict your further search to the box with $m$ defined by this smaller vector.

Comment: This method is guaranteed to produce the optimal solution, but the calculation time is exponential in $d$.

Comment: If you are concerned with calculation time, you may be interested in the [LLL-lattice reduction algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm#Applications).

Comment: Thanks! It is interesting to know that such an algorithm exists.  However, my problem is slightly different from lattice reduction, the task of finding of minimal integer linear combinations of integer vectors.  In my problem, the goal is to find the minimal linear combination of integer vectors that is an integer vector; the coefficients don't have to be integers.

Comment: Good point. Of course the coefficients must be rational, and taking $x\in\Bbb{Z}^d$ and a basis $B=\{y_2,\ldots,y_d\}$ for its orthogonal complement with $y_i=x_ie_1-x_1e_i$, the denominator of the coefficient of $y_i$ must divide $\gcd(x_1,x_i)$. So perhaps a workaround is possible with the fact that all coefficients are integer multiples of $\tfrac{1}{N}$ where
$$N=\operatorname{lcm}_{1<i\leq d}\gcd(x_1,x_i).$$
Of course not *every* integer linear combination of $\{\tfrac{1}{N}y_2,\ldots\tfrac{1}{N}y_d\}$ has integer coefficients...

Comment: `the denominator of the coefficient of yi must divide gcd(x1,xi)` I don't think that is correct.  We want $Y = \alpha_2y_2 +\dots +\alpha_d y_d$ to be an integer vector, but it is not the case that each $\alpha_i y_i$ needs to be an integer vector.  for instance, let $x=(3,5,8),\; y_2 = (5,-3,0), \;y_3 = (8,0,-3)$  Then a minimal linear combination of $y_2$ and $y_3$ resulting in an integer vector is $\frac{1}{3}(y_3-y_2)$

Comment: @Aqualone Perhaps you are right. The denominator must divide $x_1$ though, because
$$y_i=(x_i,0,0,\ldots,0,x_1,0,\ldots,0).$$ 
That is to say, because for $i\geq2$ we have $(y_i)_i=x_1$ and $(y_j)_i=0$ if $j\neq i$. It follows that all coefficients are integer multiples of $\frac{1}{x_1}$.